# mysql event scheduler backup database

Tags: php, html, mysqli

I got a question about how to save a backup to another database with event scheduler and a timer every 4 hours it do a backup to the another database.

If that works, then I got a further question about a php script, I was thinking to make a php table about that so my administration team can download the backups on a page.

I was thinking the table was going to look like this on the php page

TS = time stamp what time when the database did the backup

```
+-----+-------------+-------------+
| TS  |Database name| Download btn|
+-----+-------------+-------------+
|10:00| database    | Button      |
|12:00| database    | Button      |
|14:00| database    | Button      |
|16:00| database    | Button      |
+----+--------------+-------------+
```

Comment: if you want to back up to another _database_ then maybe replication is your friend (google mysql replication). But normally you can just backup to a .sql script file, which can be used to restore your DB in case of a problem. Depending on your O/S and your exact requirements there may already be tools you can use to schedule this kind of thing automatically. e.g. on Ubuntu you can simply install the "automysqlbackup" package, and voila, daily backups, kept for a year, and rotated out automatically once they get too old. Zero effort. You can then config it if you need different frequency etc

Comment: You can probably google around for similar stuff if you have a different O/S, or you can write something based on calling the mysqldump command regularly to export from your DB to a backup file. Then if you need a window onto it, a PHP script which lists files in the backup folder and allows them to be downloaded should be pretty easy to find - any generic "view files in the folder" script will do, the content of the files doesn't really matter. I doubt you need a DB table to keep a record - what's in the folder is the record, at least until you delete the older ones.

Comment: I was unclear how do i backup a mysql database to another database

Comment: like I said, look into replication, you can find documentation online. But first consider whether backing up to another running database is actually necessary, or whether backing up to a file is sufficient (because it's much simpler). That was my point above.